# How to: Wiring an electrical pan?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a small electrical pan with a Black and Red wire inside. Recently the two legs source wire has broken and I have to cut off one inch and reconnect it.

The two legs, the heads are different, one for hot and one for neutral.

I am wondering do I have to connect the hot to Red, or the opposite, or either will be fine? (*I am in the USA.*)

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question?

Comment: Is this for internal wiring, or is it to the power cord?